# Converting binary to decimal and flipping 0 and 1 JAVA

Tags: java, binary, parseint

```
    public static int reverseIntBitwise(int value) {
    String res = String.format("%32s", 
    Integer.toBinaryString(value)).replace(' ', '0');

    char[] charArray = res.toCharArray();
    for(int i=0; i<charArray.length; i++){
        if(charArray[i] == '0'){
            charArray[i]='1';
        }else if(charArray[i]=='1'){
            charArray[i]='0';
        }
    }
    String res2 = new String(charArray);
    return Integer.parseInt(res2, 2);
}
```

So  res  = 00000000000000000000000000101110
And res2 = 11111111111111111111111111010001

but when I try to convert it back to int this is displayed in the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "11111111111111111111111111010001"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:583)
    at com.company.Main.reverseIntBitwise(Main.java:169)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:150)
```

Can anyone help with resolving this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting `NumberFormatException` because the resultant number `4294967249` is outside of range of `Integer` (i.e. more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`). You can try `BigInteger` instead, e.g.:

```
String res2 = "11111111111111111111111111010001";
System.out.println(new BigInteger(res2, 2));
```

Comment: Or `Long.parseLong()`

Comment: @Eran yes, absolutely!

Answer (score 0):

The decimal number for binary `11111111111111111111111111010001` would overflow the integer data type.

Use a long.